# DrawText and Text Clipping

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, drawtext

Is there a way to detect when the text passed to [`DrawText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) has been clipped ?

I would like to be able to draw any text in a given rectangle, (i.e. have been clipped by `DrawText`, which means that the user might miss some important part of the text).

I want to get the height required to show the clipped text.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DT_CALCRECT` flag to get the required rectangle size.  In addition, the return value of the function gives the height of the text.

From the online documentation:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the height of the text in logical units. If DT_VCENTER or DT_BOTTOM is specified, the return value is the offset from lpRect->top to the bottom of the drawn text.

Comment: It just gives the height of rectangle after truncating the string that didn't fit in the rectangle area

Comment: You call `DrawText` twice. First with `DT_CALCRECT`, then without the flag but with correct rectangle dimensions.

Comment: Call `DrawText()` with `DT_CALCRECT` and a 0-height rectangle set to the desired width.  It will return the necessary rectangle height.  Now you know the whole rectangle needed to draw the text.  Compare that to your clipping rectangle, and you will know if the text will be clipped or not.